# how to queue up sending emails to all users on e-commerce(Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I can't find any tutorials how to send multyple email using laravel.First, I thing use foreach but its get error in the future(RTO) or 404, can't handle request.
Please any help.
Thanks in advance. . .

how if use

```
Mail::queue('emails.market',$data,function($mail)use($emails,$subject,$data){
    $mail->to($firstEmailAddredd);
    $mail->to($restAllEmailAddredd);
    $mail->subject($subject);
    $mail->from($emails);
  });
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel up 6.x bro

Comment: Ok, next questions(s): 1) What are you using for your queue driver? 2) What are you using for your Email service (SMTP?)? 3) *get error in the future(RTO)*, can you post an example?

Comment: I'v never using queue before and idk how to use it. SMTP Google mail, i have more 1000 users data(including email) , it can't handle request by using foreach to send mail  by one on looping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, i'd recommend reading the documentation a few times to get a good grasp of how all of the Laravel components got together. In this case;

- **Mail**: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#queueing-mail
- **Queues**: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues

For testing email, I would also strongly recommend using a service like [MailTrap](https://mailtrap.io/) to begin with.

---

**Testing steps:**

1. Start by testing sending a single email without queuing to ensure your `Mailable` is correctly configured
2. Now queue a single email to ensure that your queue is being worked
3. Now look at sending multiple emails on the queue

**Important Note:** When sending multiple queued emails over an SMTP service provided by Google or Microsoft, it is more than likely that they have throttle to stop you sending more than "x emails every minute" (For outlook it is 20 emails a minute). You will need to respect these throttles or your emails will refused and not be sent!

Comment: can you answer what happens when i using this?Mail::queue('emails.market',$data,function($mail)use($emails,$subject,$data){
    $mail->to($firstEmailAddredd);
    $mail->to($restAllEmailAddredd);
    $mail->subject($subject);
    $mail->from($emails);
  });

Comment: including the emails inside $emails variable, that i create before;

Comment: Are you actually processing the queue? Either using `php artisan queue:listen` or via supervisor?

Comment: i dont know what you mean, sorry newbe. I'm not sure processing the queue, what you said i'v never try before

Comment: Ah that's why i suggested reading the documentation on queues ;). In your console, you will need to `cd /path/to/your/project` and then run `php artisan queue:listen` in order to process the queue. You can setup Supervisor to do this for you, again the instructions for this are in the documentation.

Comment: thanks for answer, my last question . when i configure the queue how to send it multiple, still using foreach?

Comment: `php artisan queue:listen` will poll the queue every few seconds and work the next job. So no matter how many mail items you queue, it will process them in serial. Therefore, to send multiple emails, all you need to do is a foreach loop around your `Mail::queue()` function and you are sorted